# DSNET Capturing video to a FileStream

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I was wondering if it is possible to have a filter or in anyway record video to a `Stream` (and not a Path/Video file).

So for instance, right now I have something like this:

```
hr = pRecBuilder.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Avi, VideoFileName, out mux, out pSink);
hr = pRecBuilder.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Video, m_pCaptureGraphSourceFilter, null, mux);
```

So instead of using `SetOutputFileName()` I would like something like `SetOutputFileStream()`

Does anyone have an idea on how i might be able to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want a stream? If you have a FIleStream, you should also have a file?

Comment: @CPlusSharp The framework I am working on handles saving data for me, and it is primarily built in a way that it handles Streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible, but you would need a replacement for standard File Writer filter. There is no stock implementation and I am not aware of third party filter to do that. In the same time, it is doable and such filter would accept connection from multiplexer and supply its own `IStream` implementation to accept the data.